# What is the largest positive integer less than $(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{5})^6$

Tags: number-theory

What is the largest positive integer less than $(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{5})^6$  I know that the expression is equal to $\frac{1}{(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5})^6}$ but I dont know what to do next

Hints and solutions would be appreciated

Taken from the 2013 AITMO

Comment: Do you mean "the largest positive integer in the expansion of..."?

Comment: Hint:  what is $(\sqrt6+\sqrt5)^6+(\sqrt6-\sqrt5)^6$?

Comment: It's equal to $10581$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

Evaluate $(\sqrt6+\sqrt5)^6+(\sqrt6-\sqrt5)^6$ using the binomial theorem.

Note that terms with odd powers cancel, and terms with even powers are duplicated.

Note that $(\sqrt6-\sqrt5)^6<1$.

The numerical answer given in comments is correct and can be derived using these hints.

Comment: It’s $2(6^3+15\times5\times6^2+15\times5^2\times6+5^3)-1$

Answer (score 6):

Let $x_n=(\sqrt6+\sqrt5)^{2n}+(\sqrt6-\sqrt5)^{2n}$.  Show that $x_0=2$, $x_1=22$, and $$x_{n+2}=22x_{n+1}-x_n.$$
Then compute $x_2$ and $x_3$ from this formula.  You can then find $$\lfloor(\sqrt6+\sqrt5)^6\rfloor=x_3-1.$$

Comment: Good one. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$$(\sqrt6+\sqrt5)^6=966\sqrt{30}+5291.$$

Then
$$5290<966\sqrt{30}<5291$$

because by squaring

$$27984100<27994680<27994681.$$